# How to Change Navigation Bar Color

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need give a custom color to my navigation bar.But I am not intended to use an image.Is there any way to change the navigation bar color other than using an image.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RGB values to make a color and can set it to your navigation bar.

```
yourNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.31 green:0.66 blue:0.83 alpha:1.00];
```

Comment: ...or use the convenience methods offered by UIColor, e.g. [UIColor blackColor].

Comment: This did not work. Had no effect to be precise.  But setBarTintColor: did work. I'm using Xcode 10.1.  Deployment target 9.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
navBar.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];  
// barTintColor sets the background color

navBar.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
// tintColor sets the buttons color of the navigation bar

navBar.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective C and In IOS 7 navigation bar has a property

### barTintColor

in your view controller.h file make a property of your navigationbar like this.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *mynavbar;
```

And in your viewcontroller.m file call that this method change your navigationbar color.

```
mynavbar.barTintColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

thanks in advance.